# Оцените верстку

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, инспекция-кода

Первый сверстанный макет.

Подскажите:
 - какие ошибки допущены?
 - как можно улучшить и минимизировать верстку?

[Ссылка](https://w3css.github.io/) | [PSD](https://yadi.sk/d/O66wHH343EdRGU)

Comment: Нашел в консоли "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Вероятно неверная ссылка на favicon . Плюс, я бы добавил прилипающий к низу страницы футер, потому что если вдруг не будет залито содержимого, может получится так http://prntscr.com/edtz9o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормальный main_page. Чувствуется стандартизация шаблонов опенкарт (или это логотип навеял), но всё на уровне. Доработайте второй уровень вложенности в главном меню. Блок NEWSLETTERS - задайте outline:none для кнопок, инпутов и т.п., что бы избавиться от рамок на скруглённых элементах управления. Добавьте карусельки там, где они предусмотрены для наглядности. По w3c 0 ошибок - это очень хорошо, даже не смотря на то что одна страничка.

В целом для первой задачи по вёрстке очень достойно.

Comment: https://psdfreebies.com/psd/multipurpose-ecommerce-website-template-psd/

Comment: Норм) шаблон-то хороший))

Comment: @Nick Volynkin обратите внимание, по линку, что вы нашли, лежит псд макет но не html шаблон. Может, взаправду сверстал.

Comment: Ага, я это понял через полчаса где-то после того, как комментарий оставил. К авторству претензий нет. Просто код должен быть в самом вопросе, иначе автор с гитхаба сайт удалит и вопрос потеряет смысл.

Comment: Вообще, я ещё ни разу не видел у нас запросов на ревью (инспекцию) кода вёрстки. Не могу даже порекомендовать что-то конкретное. Тут по идее можно в сниппет запихать целую страницу, но кода не должно быть слишком уж много.

Comment: Если у вас есть опыт ревью вёрстки, можете высказаться на Мете, это будет ценно. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-code-review

Comment: Можно ли выставлять ревью верстки в качестве конкурса?